# How to implement geoip in node.js and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, node.js, geolocation, express, socket.io

I have seen few examples of using geoip in node.js such as https://github.com/kuno/GeoIP.git and https://github.com/wadey/node-geoip. However what i want is to display the map showing geoip for the particular loged in user.How can it be implemented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a geolocation database (such as from http://www.maxmind.com) and store it in mongo. Each record contains an IP range (start/end) and the latitude/longitude associated with that IP range. IPs are represented as integers. You could create an index on the `start` field, and do a query on mongo to find the record with the largest value of `start` which is smaller than the IP of your client user, and look up the corresponding lat/lon.

As for plotting a map with this lat/lon, it's very easy to create a google map which is centered on a particular location: (View source at: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/map-simple.html)

There are a lot of different ways of storing/querying geolocation data, but this is just one possible approach using mongo that might work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Is there any example explaining ur concept.I don't know how to store it in mongodb.Can u provide me the sample code explaining your concept.

Comment: I have added the post method where i add the user information to the database(mongodb). To display the user information i have provided the  index.jade file.I can display all the information on the click of a button and use hidden form parameters to retrieve the values, but what i want is to display the information without the use of button i.e when the form loads

Answer (score 4):

The best module for GeoIP is https://github.com/kuno/GeoIP in my opinion (I actually used this module for a project and it worked perfectly for me). You have to download the database from Maxmind and also install some OS specific libraries and then compile the module.

There is no need to put the database into MongoDB unless you want to replicate easily across multiple servers. You can just put your database into a file and provide the path in the Node.js module.

Here is an example:

```
// Open the GeoLiteCity.dat file first.
var City = geoip.City;
var city = new City('/path/to/GeoLiteCity.dat');
console.log(city); // this contains country, city, lat, long, continent, postal code etc
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just published an NPM module for the [IPLocate.io API](https://www.iplocate.io) which I created, which lets you find the location (city, country and coordinates) based on an IP address.

Super easy, no databases to download, and 1,500 free requests per day.

### Install

`npm install node-iplocate`

### Usage

```
const iplocate = require("node-iplocate");

iplocate("8.8.8.8").then(function(results) {
  console.log("IP Address: " + results.ip);
  // IP Address: 8.8.8.8
  console.log("Country: " + results.country + " (" + results.country_code + ")"); 
  // Country: United States (US)
  console.log("Continent: " + results.continent); 
  // Continent: North America
  console.log("Organisation: " + results.org + " (" + results.asn + ")"); 
  // Organisation: Google LLC (AS15169)

  console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
  /*
    {
      "ip": "8.8.8.8",
      "country": "United States",
      "country_code": "US",
      "city": null,
      "continent": "North America",
      "latitude": 37.751,
      "longitude": -97.822,
      "time_zone": null,
      "postal_code": null,
      "org": "Google LLC",
      "asn": "AS15169"
    }
  */
});

// Or with callbacks
iplocate("8.8.8.8", null, function(err, results) {
  // ...
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
});

// Provide an API key from IPLocate.io
iplocate("8.8.8.8", { api_key: "abcdef" }).then(function(results) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Python Implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding: utf-8
import os
import pygeoip


gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoIP.dat')
gic = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoIPCity.dat')


fl = file(r'apache-unique.log')
lines = fl.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print gi.country_code_by_addr(line)
    print gic.record_by_addr(line)

os.system('pause')
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score -1):

extending mpobrien's answer-

### I found this to be easier and faster approach.

Download the binary db at maxmind

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/
http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.gz

Use node-maxmind-db

https://github.com/PaddeK/node-maxmind-db

```
var mmdbreader = require('maxmind-db-reader');

// open database
var countries = mmdbreader.openSync('./countries.mmdb');

// get geodata
app.get('/api/v1/ip/', function(req, res) {
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

    countries.getGeoData(ip, function(err, geodata) {
        if(!err && geodata.location) return res.json({success: true, location: geodata.location});
        return res.json({success: false, location: null, error: err});
    });
});
```

Then you will have user location based on his ip address which you can display on map.

Benefits-

The bindary data file is small and easy to update. No db import export.
Just swap the file and reload the data. ie- `mmdbreader.openSync()`